# What value to use for Content-Security-Policy meta for <video src="blob:...">

Tags: content-security-policy

My https://my-site.com site has some html like the following:

```
<video src="blob:https://my-site.com/{some-guid}"></video>
```

In console, I get this error:

> Refused to load media from 'blob:https://my-site.com/{some-guid}'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "media-src *".

In my `head` I have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="media-src * blob:" />
```

What am I missing? I've even tried the "catch all" (not super safe) value of `default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'`, to no avail.

Using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact the message says the CSP directive being applied is just `media-src *`—instead of `media-src * blob:`—seems to indicate the browser is already getting a stricter policy from the `Content-Security-Policy` header that trumps the more-liberal policy in your `meta` element.

So if your site is in fact already being served with a `Content-Security-Policy` header, then you’d need to change its policy to use a more-liberal `media-src` directive that allows `blob:` sources.

You can’t override a more-strict `Content-Security-Policy` header value with a more-liberal value specified with `meta` in the document. See https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#multiple-policies and https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element:

> Note: A policy specified via a `meta` element will be enforced along
>   with any other policies active for the protected resource, regardless
>   of where they’re specified. The general impact of enforcing multiple
>   policies is described in §8.1 The effect of multiple policies.
>
> #### 8.1. The effect of multiple policies
>
> The
>   behavior of an `XMLHttpRequest` might seem unclear given a site that,
>   for whatever reason, delivered the following HTTP headers:
>
> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' http://example.com http://example.net;
>                          connect-src 'none';
> Content-Security-Policy: connect-src http://example.com/;
>                          script-src http://example.com/
> ```
>
> Is a connection to example.com allowed or not? The short answer is
>   that the connection is not allowed.
>
> Enforcing both policies means that
>   a potential connection would have to pass through both unscathed. Even
>   though the second policy would allow this connection, the first policy
>   contains `connect-src 'none'`, so its enforcement blocks the connection.
>
> The impact is that adding additional policies to the list of policies
>   to enforce can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected
>   resource.

Comment: I have nginx serving the site. Perhaps that is is adding its own CSP value that's trumping it? Or maybe Apache, or the https cert? Do you know how I can view all CSPs that are being applied, maybe using Chrome Network tab? This is super helpful by the way!

Comment: I don't know about what CSP-inspection features Chrome devtools might provide, but regardless of what tools you use, you can easily check the response headers for any response to see what Content-Security-Policy it's sending. You can do that using, e.g., Postman, or curl from the command line. Or of course you can use the Network tab in devtools to see the headers.